# ARM SUB Instruction Operands

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm working with the llvm-clang compiler, compiling simple C functions down to assembly on an ARMv7-A processor. I am trying to figure out what this instruction does.

```
SUB sp, sp, #65, 30
```

Obviously it's making room on the stack pointer for some local variables, but I've never seen an ARM SUB instruction with four operands. I'm guessing that the 30 modifies the #65 somehow, but I don't know how, and I haven't been able to find details in the ARM Architecture Reference Manual. Any suggestions?

For the curious, this is at the beginning of a program that creates an 8 x 8 identity matrix of integers, so I would expect the sp to need to make room for at least 8 x 8 x 4 bytes on the stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 30 is a rotate right operation on the 65

Rotating right 30 bits is the same as rotating left 2 bitswhich is the same as a multiply by 4. 65 * 4 = 260

So this subtracts 260 from the stack pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Any idea why there would be a shifted immediate rather than just the number 260 (the ARM instruction specifies the immediate to be 12 bits wide, clearly enough for the constant 260)?

Comment: @Zeke: Martin's reply spells out why

Answer (score 5):

The arm design allocates 12 bits for immediate values, 8 bits for the value and the remaing 4 bits are a rotate right (represeting rotates of 0 2 4 etc. places). Since 260 cant be represented in 8 bits its constructed as 65*4.

This spreads out the immediate values available to the programmer over the whole 32bit range rather than restrict it to 0 to 4095

Answer (score 1):

The ARM disassemblers sometimes spit out constants in this format as the 8-bit constant + 4-bit ROR encoding allows some values to be encoded in different ways. e.g. 1 can be encoded as 1 ROR 0, 4 ROR 2, 16 ROR 4, etc.

Decoding to this format allows the instruction encoding to be unambiguously specified and allows the exact instruction to be re-assembled. It may be important to build a bitwise identical binary.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this as a usable format, but it would be helpful when trying to design code that can be patched in predictable fashion.  For example, if a timing-sensitive routine needs to add a number 0-65535, one could use two add-immediate instructions with a left-shift of 8 (right-shift 24) on one of them.  This would be much faster than having to load a 16-bit value from memory before the add.